# Prestashop Module from Git

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am trying to get a copy of ps_cleaner to clear the dummy data from my 1.7 version of Prestashop and I can't download straight to my prestashop version so I have gone to the Git location to take a copy and upload it but that doesn't work. Is there something I have to do to take it from Git to install on Prestashop 1.7

Answer (score 1):

You should better download the zip and install directly via the system, git are not always perfectly fitting last refactoring.

Comment: It won't allow me to login to download modules though.

Comment: Anyway, if you just want to clone any module, it should in most case be compatible between 1.6 & 1.7. You just have to clone and make it available that way in the filesystem : ./modules/modulename/modulename.php

Answer (score 0):

Download module as zip file then unpack first then rename the folder name with the module name "ps_cleaner". 
I mean just remove the branch Name (_master) from your module folder (such as ps_cleaner_master), Then again create a zip and install this.

Comment: I have tried that and it just says 'This file does not seem to be a valid module zip'. Unsure what it means by that as.

Comment: It is now saying 'Installation of module pscleaner failed. The version of your module is not compliant with your PrestaShop version.' but you can download a version through the store it is just mine doesn't allow me to do that

Comment: which prestashop version do you used?

Comment: I am using 1.7, it should be updated on their git if they're allowing people to download it through the modules list.

Comment: please contact with that module author for 1.7 compatible version.